# OAuth2 Service Registry Cache not rehydrating in CAS 6.3.x

Tags: oauth-2.0, cas

I am trying to upgrade my **CAS** server to **6.3.3** from **6.2.8** and it seems the OAuth flow is not working after the upgrade. In **6.3.x** there was a feature added that cached registered services ([here is the commit](https://github.com/apereo/cas/commit/3c91ec4f7e124595a55eaa173fb7660833f69d1b)). When testing locally it seems like the cache is not being updated on a miss. Other types of registered services rehydrate the cache on misses but not the OAuth service.

Am I missing a property that needs to be set on the Service so the cache gets rehydrated? I took a look at the RegexRegisteredService and the OAuthRegisteredService interface and I didn't see anything that would indicate if the service should be cached.

I am not using the Service Management, all my services are registered at startup as beans and placed in a inMemoryRegisteredService Bean.